# Java Streams: Issue about collect to a Map<String, Object>

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I'm running against an issue:

I've created this stream I need to map to a `Map<String, Object>`:

```
private Map<String, Object> collectArguments(JoinPoint point) {
    CodeSignature signature = (CodeSignature) point.getSignature();
    String[] argNames = signature.getParameterNames();
    Object[] args = point.getArgs();

    return IntStream.range(0, args.length)
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(param -> argNames[param], param -> args[param]));
}
```

I'm getting the following message, which I don't quite figure out:

```
[Java] Type mismatch: cannot convert from Collector<Object,capture#3-of ?,Map<Object,Object>> to Supplier<R>
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`IntStream` doesn't have a `collect` method that accepts a `Collector`. It only has a 3 argument `collect` method having this signature:

```
<R> R collect(Supplier<R> supplier,
              ObjIntConsumer<R> accumulator,
              BiConsumer<R, R> combiner)
```

Perhaps you should use a `Stream<Integer>`:

```
return IntStream.range(0, args.length)
                .boxed()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(param -> argNames[param],
                                          param -> args[param]));
```

Or, if you wish to use the `collect` method of `IntStream`, it would look like this:

```
return IntStream.range(0, args.length)
                .collect(HashMap::new,
                         (m,i)->m.put(argNames[i],args[i]),
                         (m1,m2)->m1.putAll (m2));
```

or

```
return IntStream.range(0, args.length)
                .collect(HashMap::new,
                         (m,i)->m.put(argNames[i],args[i]),
                         Map::putAll);
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to [Eran's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53261962/1421925) (in which the first variant, to use a `Stream<Integer>` is really neat) would be to first map the content of the arrays to an object:

```
public class Argument {
  private final String argName;
  private final Object arg;

  public Argument(String argName, Object arg) {
    this.argName = argName;
    this.arg = arg;
  }

  public String getArgName() {
    return argName;
  }

  public Object getArg() {
    return arg;
  }
}
```

The code for collecting this object to a map becomes a very clear and concise basic stream:

```
Map<String, Object> map = IntStream.range(0, args.length)
    .mapToObj(i -> new Argument(argNames[i], args[i]))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Argument::getArgName, Argument::getArg));
```

Perhaps even extract the logic for creating `Argument`s into its own method:

```
private List<Argument> toArguments(JoinPoint point) {
  String[] argNames = ((CodeSignature) point.getSignature()).getParameterNames();
  return IntStream.range(0, point.getArgs().length)
      .mapToObj(i -> new Argument(argNames[i], point.getArgs()[i]))
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Doing this, your `collectArguments()` method would be a simple one-liner:

```
private Map<String, Object> collectArguments(JoinPoint point) {
  return toArguments(point).stream().collect(toMap(Argument::getArgName, Argument::getArg));
}
```